# d3.v4: How to set ticks every Math.PI/2

Tags: d3.js

In the d3.v4 [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#axis_ticks) the following is stated:

> To generate ticks every fifteen minutes with a time scale, say:
>
> ```
> axis.tickArguments([d3.timeMinute.every(15)]);
> ```

Is there a similar approach that can be used with values other than time? I am plotting sine and cosine curves, so I'd like the ticks to begin at -2*Math.PI, end at 2*Math.PI, and between these values I'd like a tick to occur every Math.PI/2. I could, of course, explicitly compute the tick values and supply them to the tickValue method; however, if there is a simpler way to accomplish this, as in the time-related example quoted above, I'd prefer to use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the end ticks and specifying the precise space of the ticks in a linear scale is a pain in the neck. The reason is that D3 axis generator was created in such a way that the ticks are automatically generated and spaced. So, what is handy for someone who doesn't care too much for customisation can be a nuisance for those that want a precise customisation.

My solution here is a *hack*: create **two** scales, one linear scale that you'll use to plot your data, and a second scale, that you'll use only to make the axis and whose values you can set at your will. Here, I choose a `scalePoint()` for the ordinal scale.

Something like this:

```
var realScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([10,width-10])
    .domain([-2*Math.PI, 2*Math.PI]);

var axisScale = d3.scalePoint()
    .range([10,width-10])
    .domain(["-2 \u03c0", "-1.5 \u03c0", "-\u03c0", "-0.5 \u03c0", "0",
        "0.5 \u03c0", "\u03c0", "1.5 \u03c0", "2 \u03c0"]);
```

Don't mind the `\u03c0`, that's just **π** (pi) in Unicode.

Check this demo, hover over the circles to see their positions:

```js
var width = 500,
    height = 150;
var data = [-2, -1, 0, 0.5, 1.5];

var realScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([10, width - 10])
    .domain([-2 * Math.PI, 2 * Math.PI]);

var axisScale = d3.scalePoint()
    .range([10, width - 10])
    .domain(["-2 \u03c0", "-1.5 \u03c0", "-\u03c0", "-0.5 \u03c0", "0", "0.5 \u03c0", "\u03c0", "1.5 \u03c0", "2 \u03c0"]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 8)
    .attr("fill", "teal")
    .attr("cy", 50)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return realScale(d * Math.PI)
    })
    .append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
        return "this circle is at " + d + " \u03c0"
    });

var axis = d3.axisBottom(axisScale);

var gX = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,100)")
    .call(axis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm ambivalent about your solution. It solves the particular problem I stated. But what I'm trying to avoid is hand-coding the output as in your:

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid the simple answer is "no" (*Is there a similar approach that can be used with values other than time?*). Besides that, let me ask you: you know exactly what values you want to show, but you don't want to hardcode them. Why?

Comment: SO cut off my editing of the previous comment. So here's the full comment, which answers your question I think: I'm ambivalent about your solution. It solves the particular problem I stated. But what I'm trying to avoid is hand-coding the output as in your expression: ["-2 \u03c0", "-1.5 \u03c0", "-\u03c0", "-0.5 \u03c0", "0", "0.5 \u03c0", "\u03c0", "1.5 \u03c0", "2 \u03c0"]); I was hoping that d3 could generate that for me, or at least generate the tick marks placed at spacings of pi/2. This way, if the user, or coder, happens to change the domain everything would adjust automatically.

Comment: D3 axis *does* adjust automatically, but unfortunately not the way you want. What you can do is creating a function to set the domain array, just like in my answer, and make *that* function adjusting automaticaly.

Comment: That sounds do-able. Thanks for clarifying the situation.

Comment: By the way, in your html do you declare utf-8, or some other? This, relevant to generating the pi symbols.

Comment: Yes, it is utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement an x axis in units of PI/2, under program control (not manually laid out), by targetting the D3 `tickValues` and `tickFormat` methods. The call to `tickValues` sets the ticks at intervals of PI/2. The call to `tickFormat` generates appropriate tick labels. You can view the complete code on GitHub:
https://github.com/quantbo/sine_cosine

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to customise tickValues and tickFormat. Only 1 scale is needed, and delegate [d3.ticks](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#ticks) function to give me the new tickValues that are proportional to Math.PI.

```
const piChar = String.fromCharCode(960);
const tickFormat = val => {
    const piVal = val / Math.PI;
    return piVal + piChar;
};

const convertSIToTrig = siDomain => {
    const trigMin = siDomain[0] / Math.PI;
    const trigMax = siDomain[1] / Math.PI;
    return d3.ticks(trigMin, trigMax, 10).map(v => v * Math.PI);
};

const xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([-Math.PI * 2, Math.PI * 2]).range([0, 600]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
    .tickValues(convertSIToTrig(xScale.domain()))
    .tickFormat(tickFormat);
```

This way if your xScale's domain were changed via zoom/pan, the new tickValues are nicely generated with smaller/bigger interval